# Remove elements less than previous element in an ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

i have a question about the code written below. Elements in the ArrayList that are less than their previous Elements must be removed and print the array without these elements . for example: Input: 2 2 1 3 4 6 -5 10 3 Output: 2 2 3 4 6 10

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, n, num;

        ArrayList f;

        f = new ArrayList();

        Console.Write("Length: ");

        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Element#{0} : ", i + 1);
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            f.Add(num);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < f.Count; i++)
        {
            if (f[i] < f[i - 1])
            {
                f.Remove(i);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < f.Count; i++)
        {
            object value = f[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Element#{0}: {1}", i + 1, value);
        }


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean remove elements that are less than the previous value?  Because you remove 1 and the previous value is 2

Comment: You mentioned you have a question about the code, what's the question?

Comment: You have to decrement the index when you remove something when moving forward through a collection.  Also consider using `List<int>` as `ArrayList` is a left over from before generics.

Comment: for(i = 0; i < f.Count; i++)
        {
            if (f[i] > f[i - 1])
            {
                f.Remove(i);
            }
        } this part of the code does not work but I think it is spelled correctly

Comment: Also if comparing the current to the last you need to start at 1 and not 0, otherwise the first check is going to try to access index -1 and fail.

Comment: And based on the example you should be doing `f[i] < f[i-1]` but currently your example and the text do not match up and you need to fix that.

Comment: Instead of removing items from the ArrayList maybe try adding just the items you want to keep to a new ArrayList and use that as the result

Comment: i get the following error for "f[i] < f[i - 1]" :" cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and object'" how do i compare objects?

Comment: When removing items from a list you have to start from the end and move towards the beginning.  If you have 4,5,6 and remove 4 you end up skipping 5.  Try following : for(i = Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { your code here}

Comment: well but what to do with if statement?